# Extract text on the left side of punctuation in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a string and want to extract text on both sides of a `:`. Of course, regex and `gsub` will help here. Unfortunately, my regex skills tend to zero. Can anyone help?

```
line <- "Mrs. Villiers: I assure my right hon. Friend that I shall come to that in due course. I have great sympathy with his observation."
```

The result should be two objects (it does not matter if it is achieved in more than one step):

```
mrs 
"Mrs. Villiers"

text
"I assure my right hon. Friend that I shall come to that in due course. I have great sympathy with his observation."
```

Comment: may i know the reason for the edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `strsplit`

```
strsplit(line, ':\\s*')[[1]]
#[1] "Mrs. Villiers"                                                                                                     
#[2] "I assure my right hon. Friend that I shall come to that in due course. I have great sympathy with his observation."
```

Or another option is `scan`

```
trimws(scan(text=line, sep=':', what=''))
```

As @AnandaMahto mentioned in the comments, `scan` also has `strip.white` argument

```
scan(text=line, sep=':', what='', strip.white=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `strsplit` :

```
strsplit(line,": ")[[1]]
# [1] "Mrs. Villiers"                                                                                                      
# [2] "I assure my right hon. Friend that I shall come to that in due course. I have great sympathy with his observation."
```